# Joomla/DjCatalog2 URL duplication

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

Right now, I'm picking up some projects made by a different person and one of those projects is a website on Joomla running DjCatalog 2.
Let's say I have an item, and a category it belongs to.
The item is accessible via both site.com/category/item and site.com/item while I want it to only be accessible via site.com/item.
To my knowledge, DirectAlias doesn't work together with DjCatalog.

Comment: To specify, I've been trying to find solutions online for the duplicate URLs problem and the ones I did find actually don't work with DjCatalog 2 at all.

Comment: I have also tried to modify .htaccess for mass redirects as this:
`Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)item.html /item.html [R=301,NC]` without a positive result.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing the same problem, I was able to solve it somewhat by turning on "Advanced Mode" in SEO settings. Be careful, though, as it might influence your current SE indexation, or some such.

Answer (score 1):

regarding DJ-Catalog2 and duplicate content. 
You do not need to worry as DJ-Catalog2 provides the canonical links and same product even if is available in more than one category. 
Each DJ-Catalog2 page contains Canonical Link that leads to unique URL of given product, category or producer. Search engines respect that and don't treat such pages as duplicated.